# Basic question regarding Facebook sessions using PHP

Tags: php, facebook

So I'm fairly new to Facebook dev and PHP dev so please bare with.

I've created an iframe Facebook application. I have no trouble grabbing a signed request and using that information to do basic tasks on my page.

The real problem happens when I start navigating around my application within Facebook. I seem to lose my signed request information.

I have my PHP code included on every page and I still can't retain my signed request or session.... whatever its called.

I've pasted my basic PHP code below.

```
<?php

include_once "../lib/facebook.php";

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
"appId"  => FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
"secret" => FACEBOOK_SECRET_KEY,
"cookie" => true,
"domain" => SERVER_DOMAIN
));

function parse_signed_request($signed_request, $secret) {
  list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode(".", $signed_request, 2); 

  // decode the data
  $sig = base64_url_decode($encoded_sig);
  $data = json_decode(base64_url_decode($payload), true);

  if (strtoupper($data["algorithm"]) !== "HMAC-SHA256") {
    error_log("Unknown algorithm. Expected HMAC-SHA256");
    return null;
  }

  // check sig
  $expected_sig = hash_hmac("sha256", $payload, $secret, $raw = true);
  if ($sig !== $expected_sig) {
    error_log("Bad Signed JSON signature!");
    return null;
  }

  return $data;
}

function base64_url_decode($input) {
  return base64_decode(strtr($input, "-_", "+/"));
}


session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['fb_data'])) {
    $data = $_SESSION['fb_data'];
} else {
    $data = parse_signed_request($_REQUEST["signed_request"], FACEBOOK_SECRET_KEY);
    $_SESSION['fb_data'] = $data;
}

session_write_close();

$page_id = $data["page"]["id"];
$like_status = $data["page"]["liked"];

?>
```

Comment: I have no experience with Facebook API but I don't see anything getting saved to session in your script. Unless you save your data to $_SESSION array it will be lost in another request.

Comment: So perhaps if I do something like this: 
<?php 
session_start();
$_SESSION['fb_data'] = $data;
?>
 Then I'll be able to access $fb_data to get the page ID and like status?

Comment: I guess so. If you do $_SESSION['fb_data'] = $data; then you can do $data = $_SESSION['fb_data']; in another PHP script. But again, I don't know a thing about Facebook API so it might be done differently.

Comment: See http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php for more detailed description of sessions in PHP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The signed_request is only passed into your page when it is first loaded as a Facebook Canvas page.  The signed_request is passed in as a POST variable.  If you are navigating to different pages at the iframe level instead of the top level, you will lose that signed_request parameter.

For example, when user loads this page:

```
http://apps.facebook.com/test_app/
```

Facebook will load this inside its IFrame:

```
http://yourserver.com/test_app/
```

- while passing in signed_request as a POST variable.

If you then navigate to different pages using the following  tag:

```
<a href="http://yourserver.com/test_app/page2"> Page 2 </a>
```

signed_request parameter will be lost.

Instead, you can either pass through the signed_request parameter as a GET variable:

```
<a href="http://yourserver.com/test_app/page2?signed_request=xxxxx"> Page 2 </a>
```

Or reload the page at top level:

```
<a target="_top" href="http://apps.facebook.com/test_app/page2"> Page 2 </a>
```

Comment: A+ on creating those examples! Thanks for explaining it in a little more detail, thats great! I ended going with this little guy I constructed.... [edited original post]

Answer (score 0):

In case someone stumbles on this, the latest version of Facebook's php-sdk automatically uses $_SESSION variables to persist the signed_request when it isn't passed in on a Canvas page or Tab request.  https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk